# toast message does not show up

Tags: android, kotlin, toast, android-toast

when i run my app and click on button i need to see a message but Tost doesn't work..
what's the problem?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.buttonSubmitUsername.setOnClickListener {
            if (binding.textInputUsername.text.toString().isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(this,"abc",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else{
                val intent = Intent(this,QustionActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying this toast is not appearing when you expect it to? Can you set a debug breakpoint on the Toast line to make sure the condition is satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was something wrong with my emulator...
if you have the same problem you should try another device.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you provide the complete layout file for your `MainActivity`  as well, but assuming from the naming convention `textInputUsername`, it seems you are trying to get text from your `TextInputEdittext` directly, you would have a `TextInputLayout` as well in your layout file. Try something like this:

```
binding.buttonSubmitUsername.setOnClickListener {

      if (binding.textInputLayout.edittext?.text.toString().isEmpty()){ // `textInputLayout` is the id of your TextInputLayout
          Toast.makeText(this,"abc",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
       }else{
          val intent = Intent(this,QustionActivity::class.java)
          startActivity(intent)
        }
      }
   }
}
```

But for the exact solution your layout file or some more details would be required, do tell if this fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"abc",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```